# Bootstrap Accordion Throws TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: bootstrap-5, bootstrap-accordion

I have an accordion written like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="editTournamentAccordionWrapper" class="accordion accordion-flush">
        <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="editTournamentAccordionHeading">
                <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#editTournamentAccordion" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="editTournamentAccordion">
                    Card title
                </button>
            </h2>
            <div id="editTournamentAccordion" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="editTournamentAccordionHeading" data-bs-parent="editTournamentAccordionWrapper">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                    <iframe class="w-100" style="height: 1024px;" src="www.example.com"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When i click the first time on the Accordion header, the accordion won't open and the following exception will be threw

> Uncaught TypeError: 'querySelectorAll' called on an object that does not implement interface Element. selector-engine.js:18:59

Any idea of the reason? As far as I noticed, this is the minimum code I had to wrote in order to make the bug present

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**TLDR: A `#` is missing in the `data-bs-parent` attribute.**

According to the [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/collapse/#options), the `data-bs-parent` accepts a

> selector | jQuery object | DOM element

When you pass in `data-bs-parent="id"` for the attribute, it is plain text hence belongs to none of the categories. As a result you get the `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

Working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="editTournamentAccordionWrapper" class="accordion accordion-flush">
        <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="editTournamentAccordionHeading">
                <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#editTournamentAccordion" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="editTournamentAccordion">
                    Card title
                </button>
            </h2>
            <div id="editTournamentAccordion" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="editTournamentAccordionHeading" data-bs-parent="#editTournamentAccordionWrapper">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                  Card Body
<!--                    <iframe class="w-100" style="height: 1024px;" src="www.example.com"></iframe>-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```